# Setting class attribute in jqGrid searchoptions

Tags: jqgrid

I am in the process of upgrading from jqGrid 4.5.2 to 5.5.5.  When contructing the colModel searchoptions were set as follows:

```
searchoptions: {
                sopt: ["eq", "cn", "bw"],
                value: partyStr,
                attr: { class: "grid-select2 grid-dd-autosize" }
            }
```

As of 5.5.5 the class attributes are no longer being added.  Looking at the documentation [here](https://guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#searchoptions) the attr option doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Is there a way to add a custom class to the search object on the filterToolbar with version 5.5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a way to set attribute when use searchoptions or editoptions.
The way is the same for the both.

To do what you want you need to add the attribute key in searchoptions object and not specify the attr property. To work this set it this way.

```
searchoptions: {
   sopt: ["eq", "cn", "bw"],
   value: partyStr,
   class: "grid-select2 grid-dd-autosize"
}
```

P.S. Thanks for point us for the docs. We have updated the documentation and now you can see the right way to do this. Use the same link and clear your browser cache to see the update

Comment: Ah yes, I should have tried that, it's pretty obvious now you point it out.  Thanks